# Returned variable does not exist in C#

Tags: c#, xml, class, xml-parsing

I have a dataTable "A" defined in a function called ParseByXML(). but the returned "A" cannot be used by another independent function ParseByLinq(). Is there any solution to avoid "does not exist in the current context"?

```
namespace XmlParsers.Models
{
  public static class XMLParsers
  {
    public static DataTable ParseByXML()
    {
      var A = new DataTable();
      ...
      return A;
    }

    public static DataTable ParseByLinq()
    {
      var B = from row in A 
              ...
      return B;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Both methods are static. "ParseByLinq()" has no parameters. Which way should "ParseByLinq" identify your "A" object? You should add DataTable static object in your static class. Or add input parameter in "ParseByLinq".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways:

```
namespace XmlParsers.Models
{
  public static class XMLParsers
  {
    private static DataTable A;

    public static void ParseByXML()
    {
      A = new DataTable();
      ...
    }

    public static DataTable ParseByLinq()
    {
      var B = from row in A 
              ...
      return B;
    }
  }
}
```

Or

```
namespace XmlParsers.Models
{
  public static class XMLParsers
  {
    public static void ParseByXML()
    {
      A = new DataTable();
      ...
      return A;
    }

    public static DataTable ParseByLinq(DataTable A)
    {
      var B = from row in A 
              ...
      return B;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ParseByLinq` does not know anything about `A` because it is defined in another method. You may either add a parameter to `ParseByLinq` as follows:

```
public static DataTable ParseByLinq(DataTable A) { /* ... */ }
```

Or create a static member within the class:

```
public static class XMLParsers
{
    static DataTable A;

    public static DataTable ParseByXML()
    {
        A = new DataTable();
        ...
        return A;
    }
}
```

Now you may access `A` from the `ParseByLinq`-method. However you have to call `ParseByXML` beforehead to ensure `A` is actually set to anything.

Answer (score 0):

ParseByLinq needs to accept a datatable as its argument. Then when you receive the datatable from ParseByXML you can send it to ParseByLinq.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use A in your second function without somehow telling it where to get if from. You must either call your function that will return A from withing your PareByLinq function or pass A in as an argument for example:

```
public static DataTable ParseByLinq()
{
  var A = ParseByXML();
  var B = from row in A 
          ...
  return B;
}
```

or

```
public static DataTable ParseByLinq(DataTable A)
{
  var B = from row in A 
          ...
  return B;
}
```

and in the code that calls it do something like:

```
var A = ParseByXML();
ParseByLinq(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable A do not exist on your class XMLParsers. So on of the way to do this is to change you method

```
  public static DataTable ParseByLinq()
    {
      var B = from row in ParseByXML()
          ...    
      return B;
    }
```

You can leave your two methods as static if you want. But others ways in this post are OK